# Connecting swift into web service

Tags: ios, swift, web-services, xcode7

Hey guys I'm kinda new into swift programming, currently I'm making an iOS apps and facing a problem

I have one textfield and one textview in my view controller, I'm supposed to connect the application into a web service, so when I input number in the textfield, the apps will print the return value in the textview. But i don't know what to code in the Xcode to communicate the apps with the server.

This is the code of the web service

```
<?php error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_PARSE); 
include 'koneksi.php';
  $nama = $_REQUEST['nama'];
  $query = ("select * from pegawai where nip='$nama' or no_kpe='$nama'");
  $exe = mysql_query($query);
  if($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($exe)){

$c = TRIM($row['nama']);
$a = NUMBER_FORMAT($row['tht']);
$b = NUMBER_FORMAT($row['pensiun']);    

if($a == 0){
    echo "Nama = ".$c."\n";
    echo "THT = Sedang Dilakukan Peremajaan Data Keluarga"."\n";
    echo "Pensiun = Rp. ".$b;
    }
    else{
    echo "Nama = ".$c."\n";
    echo "THT = Rp. ".$a."\n";
    echo "Pensiun = Rp. ".$b;
        }                
     }
    else {
    echo "Mohon Periksa Kembali Notas atau No. KPE anda."."\n";
    }
?>
```

I'm using Xcode 7 and running the apps in iOS 9.0

I'm new in this language and also web service so step by step answer will be much appreciated

Comment: What difficulty are you facing? Building the UI in the iOS app? Interacting with the UI in Swift? Communicating with the web server? Unexpected behaviour on the server side? Please clarify.

Comment: The current problem is communicating with the web server

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the [`NSURLSession`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/URLLoadingSystem.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000165i) API to connect to a remote web service. I suggest using [`AFNetworking`](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking). It is an easy to use framework that makes network request and serialization for you.